Is there any etymological connection between the two dominant meanings of "or"?
Did "or" meaning gold and "or" meaning "yet/but" come from completely different etymological sources to become the same word, or did they have overlapping roots?
I've always found this word a bit difficult to conceptualize as a conjunction partly because I come from English where or has a prominent and unrelated meaning and partly because it means gold, so it just feels odd. I'm just trying to get a better understanding of it.

This is not uncommon in French: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/41942/9870, https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52452/9870

The word "or" meaning "gold" comes from the Latin word "aurum", while the word "or" meaning "yet/but" comes from the Latin word "hora" ("hour" in English) - the word "or" meant "now" in the past.

Hmm, how did "hora" end up being used as "yet/but"?

@temporary_user_name I edited my answer adding "the word "or" meant "now" in the past" to explain how "or" eventually meant "yes/but" : "hour" -> "now" -> "yes/but".

Do you mean to be writing "yet"? You keep writing "yes" and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

@temporary_user_name Sorry, it is a typo. I meant: "or" eventually meant "yet/but" : "hour" -> "now" -> "yet/but".

Could you give a French sentence where or means yet?

@WoJ Je ne m'attendais pas à répondre, or je l'ai fait. (I hadn't expected to reply, yet I did.)

For the semantic development, consider also that now in English is often used, as Wiktionary describes it (adverb, sense 2), “to introduce a point, a qualification of what has previously been said, a remonstration or a rebuke” (as in, “Now, that wasn’t so hard, was it?”. That’s sort of in between a purely temporal meaning and a contrastive meaning like ‘yet’ or ‘but’.

@jlliagre ah right, thanks

@WoJ question for you https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65736957#65736957
